# Is there a way to filter data inside geom_point() without mentioning data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, highlight

I am trying to highlight certain data points from gapminder dataset in scatter plot with following criteria:

```
year == 2012, 
continent == Asia, 
population > median(population).
```

[image]

**Issue** I am facing is that I have to filter data each time with **year == 2012** inside each **geom_point()** layer which I think is making the same data filtering at every level again and again and unnecessary costing time and computation.

How can I filter this data once for **year == 2012** and use at all levels (don't want to create new data frame with respect to year).

**Code Below:**

```
# Creating median population for filter criteria 
med_2012_pop <- gapminder %>% 
  filter(year == 2012 & continent == "Asia") %>% 
  select(population) %>% .$population %>% median(na.rm = T)

# plotting
gapminder  %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=fertility, y=life_expectancy, color=continent)) +
  # layer 1 - highlighted
  geom_point(data = filter(gapminder, year == 2012 & continent == "Asia" & population > med_2012_pop), 
             size=5, color="gray") +
  # layer 2 - base layer
  geom_point(data = filter(gapminder, year == 2012)) +
  # layer 3 Country highlight - Japan
  geom_point(data = filter(gapminder, year == 2012 & country == "Japan"), size=1, color="black") +
  geom_label(x=1.8, y=84, label="Japan", color="black", size=3) +
  theme_minimal()
```

**When I try below code - without mentioning gapminder & year inside geom_point then it doesn't work and gives error**

```
gapminder  %>% filter(year == 2012)  %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=fertility, y=life_expectancy, color=continent)) +
  geom_point(data = filter(continent == "Asia" & population > med_2012_pop), 
             size=5, color="gray") +
  geom_point() +
  # Adding codes for Japan below
  geom_point(data = filter(country == "Japan"), size=1, color="black") +
  geom_label(x=1.8, y=84, label="Japan", color="black", size=3) 
  theme_minimal() +
```

So how can I make my code more efficient ?

Comment: Have you considered `gghighlight` package?

Comment: @Lstat I have seen couple of examples from gghighlight package but since I am just starting with R so I want to get my basics right at first and then move to packages that offer shortcuts :)

Comment: Alright, enjoy the pain :) I have reviewed your code and your "basics" are right already IMHO.

Comment: @Lstat ooh I thought I was missing something but if I have done it right then I guess its time to move to gghighlight. 
Thanks again for verifying :)

Comment: @VineetSansi why not do `df <- filter(gapminder, Year == 2012)` then use `df` in the plot?

Comment: @AllanCameron because I was further thinking of creating a user selection for year. So i didn't want to create new df each time as the user select it. But i guess that's the only possible way left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @AllanCameron points out in the comments the simplest way would be to create a new dataframe. But, if you want to "pipe it", this is one way to do it without having to repeat the name of the dataframe and the year filter:

```r
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

gapminder %>%
  filter(year == 1992) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=gdpPercap, y=lifeExp, color=continent)) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(continent == "Asia"), 
             size=5, color="gray") +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

The `gapminder` dataframe in your code is apparently not the same that I'm getting from the package (mine does not have the year 2012 and no fertility plus the columns have different names...), so I changed the example to a simpler one.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing the solution :)